# android USB debugging disappeared and not working anymore

Tags: 12.04, android, lg, adb

I was working on my project using my own device ( LG Optimus G E975 , android 4.4.2) on ubuntu 12.04, and everything was going fine, eclipse could detect the device and I could easily debug on device. Suddenly the debugging icon in status bar was gone and the only thing it now shows is the charging icon, the usb debugging is turned on in developer options. when I connect my phone to laptop and using

```
adb devices
```

it doesn't find any device. I've tried pluging the device to laptop many times and still the same. what could possibly go wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same experience:  *adb devices* was correctly indicating my LG-P705 and now it doesn't.  I have no idea why the change.  This was with Kubuntu 12.04.